# Has anyone survived triggering a bounding landmine?

Tags: war, weapons

I just watched an episode of the television series Flashpoint, where a member of the police force steps on the trigger of a "CR38 bounding mine."

Has anyone survived triggering a bounding mine in this way? What has worked and what hasn't?

Comment: Are you interested in bounding mines in general (such as the German S-Mine), or this particular model?

Comment: In general. ___

Comment: As a side note, the point of mines is not (generally) to kill in any case, with the possible exception of command detonated mines like Claymores.  Most mines are at their best when they severely wound and maim their targets, increasing the burden on the soldier's parent country to support them with medical aid and so on.  Not to mention serving as a reminder to the folks back home how much of a bad idea it was to send their sons and daughters into harms way.

Comment: @Paul I'd go further and say that the purpose of a mine is area denial through any means. Whether people get killed or maimed by them is irrelevant, it's even better if they never even get close enough to trigger them.

Comment: @jwenting eh.. that's somewhat debatable and depends on how you look at things.  Militarily, you can't actually deny an area unless you can bring direct or indirect fires on it.  I do see your point, so maybe I'm being pedantic.

Comment: I am not sure how this question is related with history and how this could be helpful for current and future users.

Comment: Another discussion [describes that scene as a Hollywood troupe](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-disarm-a-landmine-after-stepping-on-it), real landmines don't work that way; they are instant or very short delay.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

http://www.pbs.org/pov/afghanistanyear1380/the-horror-of-landmines/

> In northern Iraq, during the Persian Gulf War, for instance, we observed six casualties from the explosion of a Valmara-69. The two persons who were trying to defuse the mine to recover its aluminum content — worth about $1 on on the local market — were immediately killed. At the same time, four other people nearby, including two young shepherds, were severely injured. Only two of them survived.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-mine

> Standing still or attempting to run from the S-mine would be equally dangerous. The most effective way to survive the mine's detonation would not be to flee but to fall to the ground lying face down as quickly as possible.

Answer (score 6):

When triggered, a [bounding mine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounding_mine) propels itself into the air, then explodes, spraying shrapnel over a large area.  To maximize the effectiveness, the shrapnel pattern is largely horizontal (shrapnel thrown upwards into the air or blown into the ground at the base of the mine is wasted).

This means that, in general, the best way to survive a bounding mine is to throw yourself flat on the ground, face down.  If you're close enough, most of the shrapnel will pass over you.

The best-known bounding mines, the German [S-Mine class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-mine), had a four-second time delay on the fuse.  This gave a person or vehicle triggering the mine time to move away so they wouldn't prevent the mine from rising into the air, but it also gave them time to take evasive action if they realized they'd triggered it.

Answer (score 3):

One of my instructor once told me that he survived triggering a bounding mine. He triggered the first charge that propels the mine in the air, but then the mine hit his backpack and fall to the ground, so the wire attached to the ground which is supposed to trigger the second charge ( the one that kills people ) was not able to tense properly, so the mine did not explode.